# What is this 'nonlocal' keyword is doing is this decorator?

Tags: python, syntax, decorator, keyword

I created this decorator to save the output of a function to a csv file (so the team can easily read it).

```
def save_to_csv(directory, file_name = None):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            value = func(*args, **kwargs)

            # nonlocal file_name idk what this is doing but it works without it
            if file_name is None:
                file_name = input("File name without extension: ")
            file_path = os.path.join(directory, f"{file_name}.csv")
            with open(os.path.join(directory, file_name, ".csv"), 'w') as file:
                file.write(value)
            return value
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

But as you can see, I commented the sugested `nonlocal` keyword, and the code still works fine for the cases its used on that are:

```
@save_to_csv
def calculate_saidi(self, bus,*, file_name):
    ...
```

And

```
save_data_to_csv = save_to_cvs(dir, f"{bus_name}")(self.calculate_worse_case)
```

Searched for the uses of the nonlocal keyword, but I can't understand it's usefullness in this case and even in general.

Would you recomend I uncomment it?

Feel free to judge and ask about my code if you feel like it.

Comment: Why not ask ChatGTP in your case?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because publishing content generated by ChatGPT (not only answers) [isn't allowed currently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned)

Comment: @RuanCarloWeiersBritzke There’s more than one reason to ban AI content. Posting *any* AI content poisons the training data pool. That alone is reason enough to ban questions that include AI-generated code. How to handle this is an as-yet unsolved problem. Until it is solved, no AI content.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `nonlocal` keyword to overwrite variables of a higher namespace.

For example, you could define the `file_name` at the beginning of the `decorator` function and overwrite its value inside the `wrapper` function.

It isn't needed or usefull in your specific case because it doesn't need access to `file_name`